# I need to pull specific cells from a single excel file to create a single row in SSIS

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2015, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm provided with a folder of excel files. Each represent one form with data entered in specific cells. Each file is of the same format and each would for ONE row of information to be imported into my sql server database.

I believe I can loop through each excel file in the folder, however I am having issues finding the right tools to extract these specific cells and merge them into a single row to insert into the table.

Answer (score 0):

Power Query to the rescue! :)

http://excelunplugged.com/2015/02/10/get-data-from-folder-in-power-query/

Answer (score 0):

Ended up writing some VBA instead to move the data into a tabular / List form in one excel sheet then used that Document to feed SSIS. So far, does not seem like SSIS can do that initial part.

Comment: It could do it in a script task, but then your entire package would be one script task - not much point in that.